# Why explicitly specify the type of a template argument?

Tags: c++, templates

A function template has the prototype as such:

```
template <int pot>
inline int gridMaxSelection(Eigen::Vector3f* grads, bool* map_out, 
                            int w, int h, float THFac);
```

And it's called like this:

```
  if (sparsityFactor == 1)
    numGoodPoints = gridMaxSelection<1>(grads, map, w, h, THFac);
  else if (sparsityFactor == 2)
    numGoodPoints = gridMaxSelection<2>(grads, map, w, h, THFac);
  else if (sparsityFactor == 3)
    numGoodPoints = gridMaxSelection<3>(grads, map, w, h, THFac);
  else if (sparsityFactor == 4)
    numGoodPoints = gridMaxSelection<4>(grads, map, w, h, THFac);
```

Why don't simply make the `pot` argument be function argument? Any efficiency concerns?

Answer (score 2):

No, there probably won't be any efficiency concerns either way. There usually aren't.

There *are* differences between template non-type parameters and function parameters, in terms of what you can do with them. e.g. if your function definition needs that parameter to be used in an *integral constant expression*, you have to make it a template parameter:

```
template<int n> 
void f() 
{
  static_assert(n == 42);  // ok
}
```

Because a function parameter cannot be used inside an expression that needs to be an *integral constant expression*:

```
void f(int const n) 
{
  static_assert(n == 42);  // error
}
```